# WebStorm 2017.1.4 git error

Tags: git, webstorm

I try to commit changes using WebStorm 2017.1.4, but git this error 
0 files committed, 14 files failed to commit: 'commet_for_commit' 
The Git process exited with the code -1 073 741 819